# How to convert json of one format to another format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json like

```
var UserMatrix =[{
    ID: 1,
    Name: "Sid Edelmann",
    UPI: 20483,
    Guru: "Yes",
    Views: {
        February: 12,
        March: 8,
        April: 10,
        May: 11,
        June: 8
    },
    Ratings: {
        February: 1,
        March: 2,
        April: 0,
        May: 0,
        June: 0
    },
    Comments: {
        February: 1,
        March: 1,
        April: 0,
        May: 0,
        June: 1
    },
    TotalViews: {
        FebJune: 49
    },
    TotalRatings: {
        FebJune: 3
    },
    AverageRatings: {
        FebJune: '#'
    },
    TotalComments: {
        FebJune: 3
    }
}, 
{
    ID: 6,
    Name: "Parthasarathy Perumbali",
    UPI: "999999",
    Guru: "",
    Views: {
        February: "8",
        March: "5",
        April: "4",
        May: "1",
        June: "8"
    },
    Ratings: {
        February: "2",
        March: "1",
        April: "2",
        May: "1",
        June: "2"
    },
    Comments: {
        February: "3",
        March: "0",
        April: "0",
        May: "0",
        June: "0"
    },
    TotalViews: {
        FebJune: "26"
    },
    TotalRatings: {
        FebJune: "8"
    },
    AverageRatings: {
        FebJune: "#"
    },
    TotalComments: {
        FebJune: "3"
    }
}
];
```

I want to convert this json to the following. How can I do this?

```
var blogComments = [
{
    "Name": "Sid Edelmann",
    "Month": "Feb",
    "Views": 12,
    "Ratings": 1,
    "Comments": 1
}, {
    "Name": "Sid Edelmann",
    "Month": "Mar",
    "Views": 8,
    "Ratings": 2,
    "Comments": 1
},
{
    "Name": "Sid Edelmann",
    "Month": "Apr",
    "Views": 10,
    "Ratings": 0,
    "Comments": 0
},
{
    "Name": "Sid Edelmann",
    "Month": "May",
    "Views": 11,
    "Ratings": 0,
    "Comments": 0
},
{
    "Name": "Sid Edelmann",
    "Month": "Jun",
    "Views": 8,
    "Ratings": 0,
    "Comments": 1
},
{
    "Name": "Parthasarathy Perumbali",
    "Month": "Feb",
    "Views": 8,
    "Ratings": 2,
    "Comments": 3
},
{
    "Name": "Parthasarathy Perumbali",
    "Month": "Mar",
    "Views": 5,
    "Ratings": 1,
    "Comments": 0
},
{
    "Name": "Parthasarathy Perumbali",
    "Month": "Apr",
    "Views": 4,
    "Ratings": 2,
    "Comments": 0
},
{
    "Name": "Parthasarathy Perumbali",
    "Month": "May",
    "Views": 1,
    "Ratings": 1,
    "Comments": 0
},
{
    "Name": "Parthasarathy Perumbali",
    "Month": "Jun",
    "Views": 8,
    "Ratings": 2,
    "Comments": 0
}
];
```

Comment: Months are fixed for only these values?

Comment: yep... This json is used for kendochart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made following code to work without jQuery.

The code contains comments so it is pretty self-explanatory. As a special note, my code works even if you have different number of months for different matrix entries as long as Views, Ratings and Comments has same amount of months inside one entry. I wanted to make this to work like this, because it is less hard-coded way of doing things.

See **[Js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VAw89/)** and remember to open your developer console to see the results.

The code is also here, below:

```
// UserMatrix data....

var UserMatrix =[{
    ID: 1,
    Name: "Sid Edelmann",
    UPI: 20483,
    Guru: "Yes",
    Views: {
        February: 12,
        March: 8,
        April: 10,
        May: 11,
        June: 8
    },
    Ratings: {
        February: 1,
        March: 2,
        April: 0,
        May: 0,
        June: 0
    },
    Comments: {
        February: 1,
        March: 1,
        April: 0,
        May: 0,
        June: 1
    },
    TotalViews: {
        FebJune: 49
    },
    TotalRatings: {
        FebJune: 3
    },
    AverageRatings: {
        FebJune: '#'
    },
    TotalComments: {
        FebJune: 3
    }
}, 
{
    ID: 6,
    Name: "Parthasarathy Perumbali",
    UPI: "999999",
    Guru: "",
    Views: {
        February: "8",
        March: "5",
        April: "4",
        May: "1",
        June: "8"
    },
    Ratings: {
        February: "2",
        March: "1",
        April: "2",
        May: "1",
        June: "2"
    },
    Comments: {
        February: "3",
        March: "0",
        April: "0",
        May: "0",
        June: "0"
    },
    TotalViews: {
        FebJune: "26"
    },
    TotalRatings: {
        FebJune: "8"
    },
    AverageRatings: {
        FebJune: "#"
    },
    TotalComments: {
        FebJune: "3"
    }
}
];

/** 
 * Yay! Method for converting UserMatrix to blogComments
 *
 */
function convertUserMatrixToBlogComments() {

    // Final format
    var blogComments = [],

    // Current matrix entry
    userMatrix,

    // Months
    months = {};

    // Loop each object in UserMatrix
    for(var i=0; i < UserMatrix.length; i++) {

        // Current
        userMatrix = UserMatrix[i];

        // Find out months
        for (var m in userMatrix.Views) { 
            if(userMatrix.Views.hasOwnProperty(m)) {
                // Makes container for months
                // e.g. February: "Feb"
                months[m] = m.substring(0, 3);
            }
        };

        // Go through all matrix data for months and push to comments
        for(var j in months) {
            if(months.hasOwnProperty(j)) {

                 blogComments.push({
                    Name: userMatrix.Name,
                    Month: months[j],
                    Views: parseInt(userMatrix.Views[j], 10),
                    Ratings: parseInt(userMatrix.Ratings[j], 10),
                    Comments: parseInt(userMatrix.Comments[j], 10)
                }); 
            }   
        }   

        // Next cycle starts here..
        months = {};

    }

    // We are done!
    return blogComments;

}

// Lets do this!
var blogComments = convertUserMatrixToBlogComments();

// See the results
console.log(blogComments);
```

Comment: +1 for not using jQuery and substringing the months.  Don't think a `disclaimer` is needed however as user put this in the jQuery tag which is a subset of javascript and I have a feeling he needs this to work with highcharts which is jQuery based in anycase.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker thanks and good points. I removed the disclaimer word. Although, I surrounded it with apostrophes before because I think that making more with pure js is a good thing (as jquery can't be always used or just adds additional load for smaller tasks). :) However, your jQuery code looks lean also, no doubt about that.!

Comment: No sweat, I agree that it's always leaner and meaner to go with vanilla if possible to keep overhead down :-)

Comment: @MaunoV. - I need a help.. If you are free please help me

Comment: @NiThin If you have a specific question on mind, just post it to stackoverflow? I am sure ppl will help :)

Comment: @NiThin I am not sure what you want to achieve.. but seems that you want to use js objects but you are defining them with [ array.. http://jsfiddle.net/maunovaha/R4jnJ/1/ alternatively, you could use more arrays: http://jsfiddle.net/maunovaha/R4jnJ/2/ but please, fire a new question if something still troubles you.

Comment: @MaunoV. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144428/how-to-convert-json-from-one-format-to-another

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
newUsers = [];
$.each(UserMatrix, function (i, user) {
    $.each(user.Views, function(key, value){
        newUser = {};
        newUser['Name'] = user['Name'];
        newUser['Month'] = key;
        newUser['Views'] = value;
        newUser['Ratings'] = user.Ratings[key];
        newUser['Comments'] = user.Comments[key];
        newUsers.push(newUser);
    });
});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newUsers));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/Bc4hw/

Outputs:

```
[{
    "Name": "Sid Edelmann",
    "Month": "February",
    "Views": 12,
    "Ratings": 1,
    "Comments": 1
}, {
    "Name": "Sid Edelmann",
    "Month": "March",
    "Views": 8,
    "Ratings": 2,
    "Comments": 1
}, {
    "Name": "Sid Edelmann",
    "Month": "April",
    "Views": 10,
    "Ratings": 0,
    "Comments": 0
}, {
    "Name": "Sid Edelmann",
    "Month": "May",
    "Views": 11,
    "Ratings": 0,
    "Comments": 0
}, {
    "Name": "Sid Edelmann",
    "Month": "June",
    "Views": 8,
    "Ratings": 0,
    "Comments": 1
}, {
    "Name": "Parthasarathy Perumbali",
    "Month": "February",
    "Views": "8",
    "Ratings": "2",
    "Comments": "3"
}, {
    "Name": "Parthasarathy Perumbali",
    "Month": "March",
    "Views": "5",
    "Ratings": "1",
    "Comments": "0"
}, {
    "Name": "Parthasarathy Perumbali",
    "Month": "April",
    "Views": "4",
    "Ratings": "2",
    "Comments": "0"
}, {
    "Name": "Parthasarathy Perumbali",
    "Month": "May",
    "Views": "1",
    "Ratings": "1",
    "Comments": "0"
}, {
    "Name": "Parthasarathy Perumbali",
    "Month": "June",
    "Views": "8",
    "Ratings": "2",
    "Comments": "0"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

### [*Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/yLXLF/)

```
var finalArr = [];
var months = ["February", "March", "April", "May", "June"];
UserMatrix.forEach(function (user) {
    months.forEach(function (m) {
        finalArr.push({
            Name: user.Name,
            Month: m,
            Views: user.Views[m],
            Ratings: user.Ratings[m],
            Comments: user.Comments[m]
        });
    });
});
document.getElementById('op').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(finalArr);
console.log(finalArr);
```

---

**Update**
*Specifying the months and attributes within an array might give you more flexibility while enhancing your application.*

### [*Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/yLXLF/1/)

```
var finalArr = [];
var months = ["February", "March", "April", "May", "June"];
var attr = ["Views", "Ratings", "Comments"];
UserMatrix.forEach(function (user) {
    months.forEach(function (m) {
        var newObj = {};
        newObj.Name=user.Name;
        newObj.Month = m;
        attr.forEach(function (a) {
            newObj[a]=user[a][m];
        });
        finalArr.push(newObj);
    });
});
document.getElementById('op').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(finalArr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(finalArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
var result = [];

UserMatrix.forEach(function (user) {
    var allMonths = Object.keys(user.Views);
    allMonths.forEach(function(month){
        var monthObject = {};
        monthObject["Name"] = user.Name;
        monthObject["Month"] = month.slice(0,3);
        monthObject["Views"] = user.Views[month];
        monthObject["Ratings"] = user.Ratings[month];
        monthObject["Comments"] = user.Comments[month];
        result.push(monthObject);
    });
})

console.log(result);
```