# How to convert json from one format to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I already have a json array like

```
var a = {
    report: [ 
        {
            Name: "Nitin",
            comment: [
                {
                    count: 0,
                    mName: "Feb"
                },
                {
                    count: 2,
                    mName: "Mar"
                }
            ],
            view: [
                {
                    count: 1,
                    mName: "Feb"
                },
                {
                    count: 0,
                    mName: "Mar"
                }
            ],
            rating: [
                {
                    count: 3,
                    mName: "Feb"
                },
                {
                    count: 2,
                    mName: "Mar"
                }
            ],
            Place: "Vatakara"
        },
        {
            Name: "Sachin",
            comment: [
                {
                    count: 3,
                    mName: "Feb"
                },
                {
                    count: 1,
                    mName: "Mar"
                }
            ],
            view: [
                {
                    count: 2,
                    mName: "Feb"
                },
                {
                    count: 1,
                    mName: "Mar"
                }
            ],
            rating: [
               {
                    count: 0,
                    mName: "Feb"
               },
               {
                    count: 3,
                    mName: "Mar"
               }
            ],
            Place: "Mumbai"
        }
    ]
};
```

I want to change this format of array to

```
var a = [
{
    "Name": "Nithin",
    "Month": "Feb",
    "viewCount": 1,
    "ratingCount": 3,
    "commentCount": 0,
    "place":"Vatakara"
}, {
    "Name": "Nithin",
    "Month": "Mar",
    "viewCount": 0,
    "ratingCount": 2,
    "commentCount": 2,
    "place":"Vatakara"
},
{
    "Name": "Sachin",
    "Month": "Feb",
    "Views": 2,
    "ratingCount": 0,
    "commentCount": 3,
    "place":"Mumbai"
},
{
    "Name": "Sachin",
    "Month": "Mar",
    "viewCount": 1,
    "ratingCount": 3,
    "commentCount": 1,
    "place":"Mumbai"
}
];
```

How can I convert this json using jquery?? Please help [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R4jnJ/3/)

Comment: you can use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: The first is ***not*** JSON. JSON format requires keys to be double-quoted.

Comment: Also, what have you tried, bud? :)

Comment: @CaseyFalk - http://jsfiddle.net/R4jnJ/3/

Comment: @NiThin: Update your question, please.

Comment: those are both javascript objects so you simply map from one to the other as you would do for any JS object. So which part of the mapping fails for you and how does that deviate from what you expected?

Comment: I want to do the reverse conversion of the question above. Is there any way to convert some of the existing 'key' as values in the new format by adding new key values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this <kbd>[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ragunathan/6Lc49/1/)</kbd>

```
var results = {
    report: [{
        Name: "Nitin",
        comment: [{
            count: 0,
            mName: "Feb"
        }, {
            count: 2,
            mName: "Mar"
        }],
        view: [{
            count: 1,
            mName: "Feb"
        }, {
            count: 0,
            mName: "Mar"
        }],
        rating: [{
            count: 3,
            mName: "Feb"
        }, {
            count: 2,
            mName: "Mar"
        }],
        Place: "Vatakara"
    }, {
        Name: "Sachin",
        comment: [{
            count: 3,
            mName: "Feb"
        }, {
            count: 1,
            mName: "Mar"
        }],
        view: [{
            count: 2,
            mName: "Feb"
        }, {
            count: 1,
            mName: "Mar"
        }],
        rating: [{
            count: 0,
            mName: "Feb"
        }, {
            count: 3,
            mName: "Mar"
        }],
        Place: "Mumbai"
    }]
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
var innArr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.report.length; i++) { 
            for(var j=0;j<results.report[i].comment.length;j++)
            {
                innArr[innArr.length] = { 
                    "Name": results.report[i].name, 
                    "Month": results.report[i].comment[j].mName, 
                    "comment": results.report[i].comment[j].count, 
                    "rating": results.report[i].rating[j].count, 
                    "view": results.report[i].view[j].count 
                }; 

            }

        } 
alert(JSON.stringify(innArr));
```